# Can we add custom dots in echart?

Tags: javascript, charts, echarts

*I want few custom points on x-axis of a line graph using echarts.
How to achieve the same?*

http://echarts.baidu.com/

Comment: what do you mean 'custom points' ? Could you be a bit more specific ?